# Combine multiple files with different worksheet names into data frame

Tags: r, xlsx

I am trying to combine two functions.

The first function can read and import each *.xlsx file into a separate folder

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
```

While the second function can read the single file with multiple sheets worksheets and combine a into one data frame.

```
# set the working directory 
setwd(path)
  
# accessing all the sheets 
sheet = excel_sheets("Gfg.xlsx")
  
# applying sheet names to dataframe names
data_frame = lapply(setNames(sheet, sheet), 
                    function(x) read_excel("Gfg.xlsx", sheet=x))
  
# attaching all dataframes together
data_frame = bind_rows(data_frame, .id="Sheet")
```

So, can anybody help me how to merge these two functions in one or more precisely to add possibility in the first function to applying sheet names to dataframe names and then to attaching together in data frame?

Comment: Use a `for` loop. For each file name, get the sheets and combine them.

Comment: @Harshvardhan Can you show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this?

```r
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

setwd("/Users/harshvardhan/Desktop/Dump/codes/sheets/")

read_dfs = function()
{
   # this has to initilised intelligently based on what the variables are
   df_complete = tibble(var1 = numeric(),
                        var2 = numeric(),
                        var3 = numeric())
      
   # listing all files in the directory
   file.list = list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
   
   # first loop for all files
   for (book in file.list)
   {
      # getting sheets in this workbook
      sheet = excel_sheets(book)
      
      # second loop for all sheets
      for (s in sheet)
      {
         df = read_excel(path = book, sheet = s)
         df_complete = rbind(df_complete, df)
      }
      
   }
   
   return(df_complete)
}

read_dfs()
#> # A tibble: 20 × 3
#>     var1  var2  var3
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1     2     7
#>  2     2     3     8
#>  3     3     4     9
#>  4     4     5    10
#>  5     5     6    11
#>  6     1     2     7
#>  7     2     3     8
#>  8     3     4     9
#>  9     4     5    10
#> 10     5     6    11
#> 11     1     2     7
#> 12     2     3     8
#> 13     3     4     9
#> 14     4     5    10
#> 15     5     6    11
#> 16     1     2     7
#> 17     2     3     8
#> 18     3     4     9
#> 19     4     5    10
#> 20     5     6    11
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>